# Spring form ModelAttribute List binding

Tags: spring, forms, modelattribute

There are way to bind List object by using spring modelAttribute? 
Actually, I know that it can be done by using Wrapper class having list member variable. 
like this

**Dto :**

```
public class SampleDto {

    private List<SubSampleDto> sampleList;
}
```

**Controller :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample/insert.ajax")
    public String set(@ModelAttribute("sampleDto") SampleDto dto) {
      ...
    }
```

But, I want to know the way not to use wrapper class. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could bind it like,

```
@ModelAttribute("sampleList")
public List<SubSampleDto> getAll() {
return subSampleDtoService.getAll(); //or something to get SubSampleDto list
}
```

if i understood you correctly